# Gnome2 applets/application shortcuts in Gnome3/Gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm a user who prefers gnome2 and compiz. For quite some time now I have been leaning on gnome-flashback and gnome2/compiz to provide my environment. But I do see the writing on the wall, however - gnome3 > gnome2 right? So I'm trying to get used to gnome3 but I'm finding that there is a lack of some of the functionality I had grown accustomed to in gnome2. For now, I will just ask about this one thing but I have been documenting all of my frustrations and desires here - https://defaria-general.blogspot.com/2020/07/migrating-to-gnome3gnome-shell-things-i.html. Also, if anybody knows of a site like "Gnome3 for Gnome2 users" I'd appreciate a pointer.

Presently:

**Configuring Application Shortcuts**: Perhaps the biggest thing I miss is configuring application shortcuts in gnome-panel. I used to have app shortcuts for various applications and things I frequently do. I had shortcuts for Chrome, Firefox, Thunderbird as well as things like invocations of gnome-terminal for a local terminal, but also for terminals that ssh to my laptop or my server in the cloud. I also have shortcuts there that merely execute a script like screensaver.sh or lightsout.sh which are bash scripts that either invoke the screensaver or turn off the screens. I had shortcuts starting nautilus on various different directories like /tmp, /Videos, /Music, /Pictures, etc. In Gnome3 I can "Add to favorites" which will put them in the dock but all that does is launch the application, not launch the application with some specific parameters. I don't see how I can add to the dock a button to run a script. Also, I'd prefer multiple "icons", one for each terminal that I start, etc. Instead, I get one button and must right click on say Terminal then select New Window which gets me a new local terminal, then ssh mars to ssh to my laptop. Contrast that with one configured button that you simply click on.

Comment: Modern GNOME Shell is too simple. GNOME FlashBack is dumb and non-functional. [MATE DE](https://mate-desktop.org/) may be a solution for your needs. Check visual tour [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-focal-fossa-release-notes/).

Comment: I did look at Mate before. It's based on Gnome2. Installing it just to try it out felt to me like stepping backward. I want to move forward. Surely there are ways to do what I'm looking to do. Gnome shell can't be this simple right? I mean what do people do?

I did install gnome-panel and I guess I could expand on that but again seems like I'm going backward.

Comment: The GNOME is now occupied by javascript genius programmers, so it is not what traditional users need. The last normal GNOME FlashBack version was 3.4 presented in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, gnome-panel was very usable here. For now the traditional GNOME is dead. So I highly encourage you to try MATE and customize it for your needs. You can choose any look and feel in MATE Tweak application. Download LiveUSB and play with it. If you want to try it on your current system use `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^` and then choose it on login screen and forget GNOMEs Hell nightmare.